# How does prctl, set_pdeathsig work in perl?

Tags: linux, perl

perl-5.24.0 on RH7

I'd like a forked process to kill itself when it determines that it's parent dies.  I've read that I can use Linux::Prctl, set_pdeathsig() to do that. But my test of this doesn't seem to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

my $pid = fork();
  die if not defined $pid;

if($pid == 0) {
    do_forked_steps();
}

print "====PARENT===\n";
print "Hit <CR> to kill parent.\n";
my $nocare = <>;

exit;

sub do_forked_steps {
    system("/home/dgauthie/PERL/sub_fork.pl");
}
```

And sub_fork.pl is simply...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use Linux::Prctl;

Linux::Prctl::set_pdeathsig(1);

sleep(300);

exit;
```

(I believe sending "1" tp set_pdeathsig = SIGHUP.  But I also tried "9".  Same results)

When I run the first script, I can see both procs using ps in another window.  When I hit  in the script to kill it, I can see that proc go away, but the second one, the forked process, remains.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You have *three* processes, not two, because `system` forks. They are:

1. The parent process in the parent script (`$pid != 0`) which waits on `<>` and calls `exit`.
2. The child process, created by `fork` in the parent script, which calls `system`. `system` forks and then `wait`s for its child to exit before returning.
3. The child process *created by `system`* which execs your child script, calls prctl, and sleeps.

When you press enter, process #1 dies, but process #2 does not, and since process #2 is the parent of process #3, the `PDEATHSIG` is never invoked.

Changing `system` to `exec` in your first script, so that a third process isn't created, causes the `PDEATHSIG` to fire in your toy problem, but without more information it isn't clear if that's suitable in the "real world" version of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215924/discussion-between-hobbs-and-ikegami).

Comment: Thanks for the reply :-)   
But what does it matter what proc#2 is doing, even a system(), if the parent died ?  I would think that proc#2 would get the interrupt then die (taking proc#3 down with it).
BTW, it works with "exec" as you suggested.  I just don't understand why it fails with system().  Thanks Again !

Comment: @daveg nothing at all happens to #2... it isn't the one that asked to be notified if its parent dies, #3 is.

Comment: But #2 has the... "Linux::Prctl::set_pdeathsig(1);".  How is that not asking for notification ?

Comment: @daveg that's not #2, that's #3.